# Kucoin Exchange Kline Get API Response is wrong

Tags: api

hey guys does somebody know why i dont get the correct response from thhis api call:

```html
https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/kline?symbol=LTC-BTC&type=1hour&from=1517446866&to=1518311025&limit=1000
```

it should give me normaly a couple of candelstick data back
i have code already for other exchanges with her api and did not have problems
but this one i dont know if i make somethink wrong or maybe the api from this exchange have a error

the documentation site is this:  https://kucoinapidocs.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/market/get-kline-data(open)

Answer (score 2):

### You are using an outdated API.

KuCoin switched to TradingView as its chart software. This is why you have https://www.kucoin.com/#/trade.pro/LTC-BTC as the default view for trading. You can still access the old view via https://www.kucoin.com/#/trade/LTC-BTC.

Looks like the API call you are using was made for the *old version*.

**Use this URL instead:**
https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/chart/history

**Working URL:**
https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/chart/history?symbol=LTC-BTC&type=1hour&from=1517446866&to=1518311025&limit=1000

For more information about the new API call: (notice how it says *tradingview-version!)*
https://kucoinapidocs.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/market/get-kline-data(open,-tradingview-version)